# Cannot access a cookie with JWT cookie in Playframework Scala

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework, keycloak

I store a JWT token in cookies which is named 'token'.
Whenever I try to access it from my Action it doesn't see it:

```
val token = request.cookies.get("token") match {
            case Some(cookie) => cookie.value
            case None => " "
        }
```

token is always " "

I also tried printing all cookies by accessing request.cookies and it sees all cookies that I setup manually. I tried renaming the cookie key from token to something else it still doesn't work.

SameSite, HttpOnly and Secure are not set.

What can go wrong? The size of my cookie is 1700

The output of request.cookies:

```
Map(test -> Cookie(test,testCookie,None,/,None,false,true.None))
```

where test is my manually created cookie

Comment: can you add the output of request.cookies

Comment: and how do you store the Token?

Comment: @pme I get it from a third-party service (Keycloak) and save it to cookies through JavaScript.

Comment: Ensure that the cookie indeed was sent in that request; look at the network tab inside the dev tools of your browser.